# Field [] used in expression does not exist in mappings, even after creating...?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, sense

I have data coming in from an external source, and one of the fields I have in Discover of Kibana is '*clearancetime*'. This field is either empty or has a timestamp in the following format:

```
January 22nd 2017, 00:00:00.000
```

I have scripted a field which uses the clearance time in a ternary statement. I think get an error in Discover that the field cleartime used in the expression does not exist in mappings. So I tried adding it via sense with the following PUT request:

```
PUT source*/_mappings/clearancetime
{
   "properties": {
      "data": {
          "type": "date"
      }
   }
}
```

I get back the response : `{ "acknowledge": true }`

But I still get the same field does not exist in mapping error.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: 
Some addiitonal error information (sorry about the format)....

```
Error: Request to Elasticsearch failed: {"error":
{"root_cause":[{"type":"script_exception",
"reason":"Field [clearancetime] used in expression does not exist in mappings"}],
"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed",
"phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":
[{"shard:0,"index":"source-raw-2017.01","node":"dewddasOSada_0vJWA",
"reason":{"type":"script_exception","reason":"Error during search with inline script 
[doc['clearancetime'].value > 0 ? doc['clearancetime'].value - doc['initialtime'].value : 0] using lang [expression]",
"caused_by":{"type":"script_exception",
"reason":"Field [clearancetime] used in expression does not exist in mappings"}}}]}}
```

The scripted field called "duration" has the following ternary expression:

```
doc['clearancetime'].value > 0 ? doc['clearancetime'].value - doc['initialtime'].value : 0
```

Comment: If you could show a snapshot of the error? and the script you used to create  your scripted field?

Comment: Your command above `source*/_mappings/cleartime` will create a new mapping type called `cleartime` not a new field called `cleartime`

Comment: @Val Hi, sorry that was meant to be a mapping for clearancetime. I have changed this in the question.... the field clearancetime exists in the real-time data coming into KIbana and can be seen under Discovery.

Comment: @Darth_Vader I have edited into the post some extra information. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What if you have your `mapping` for `clearancetime` as such, with the [index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index.html#mapping-index) parameter, which could make the field **queryable**:

```
PUT source*/_mappings/clearancetime
{
   "properties": {
      "data": {
          "type": "date",
          "index": true
      }
   }
}
```

AND since `clearancetime`'s data type is `date` shouldn't you be using the [Date Field API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/modules-scripting-expression.html#_date_field_api) in order to get the value rather than getting it as `doc['clearancetime'].value`?

Comment: I tried this but I get an error with root cause type _"mapping_parsing_exception"_ with reason: _"wrong value for index [true] for field [data]"_ . Any ideas? 
And yes I should be using that, thanks!